# How can I disable moving of texture in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Is there any way to disable "moving" of texture in OpenGL? Suppose I have some object. When I create it, I add some texture.  Point of view doesn't change. When I am morphing this object (simply change coordinates frame by frame, making some animations) texture is "moving" with vertexes. This is good in almost every case, but now I want to disable this.
How can I achieve another behavior: texture should be constant, not moving frame by frame.

Comment: Can You elaborate the notion of "moving of texture"? Usually when You alter texture coordinates the result can be some kind of movement of the patterns on the texture...

Comment: What you need is called *texture projection*.  Keywords, "texture projection opengl".

Comment: maybe texgen would work for you? http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=770639&seqNum=4

Comment: @Robinson thank you, it looks as thing I need!

Answer (score 0):

Robinson give the right answer - it is "texture projection".